# How can I find if there is a special character in String ? ex : " ] "

Tags: c#, special-characters

I do readline a long file and want to stop when readline.toString() contain a special character "]"
But my below code not worked as it not recognized and skip the target line.
Please help

```
do
   {
        //<My Func>;
        k++;
   } while (!line[k].ToString().Contains('"' + "]'" + '"'));
```

Comment: The string you're trying to match appears to be `"]'"`, is that right? That's (literal) double quote, right square brace, single quote/apostrophe, double quote.

Comment: `while (!line[k].ToString().Contains("]"));` or do you want to find the quotes as well?

Comment: @Markus you're missing a '

Comment: Where? Single quote is used on single character, double quotes on Strings.

Comment: Look closely at " ] ' ", unless that's also a mistake by OP.

Comment: Ah, but I think it is not clear, because the code differs from title.

Comment: It is not really clear what exactly you are searching. From your title its a `]` preceded and followed by a space, in your text you mention only `]` and your code actually looks for `"]'"`, that is including the double quotes

Comment: OT you can use a double quote in a string constant by "escaping" it with a backslash: `"\"]'\""`

Comment: Thanks @ALL
I found my mistake. The code is work but I were not careful deep looking to the condition. Sorry for my miss. and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Jackie if the answer is useful to others, then you are allowed to answer your own question. If it is just a typo, then it is better to delete the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but is this what it's like?

```cs
    public static void Main() 
    {
        var longText = "aadfhhhtgdfg....[]h....";

        // check type 1
        var pos = longText.IndexOf(']');
        if (pos < 0) { }

        // check type 2
        if (!longText.Contains(']')) { }

        // chech type 3
        int i = 0;
        char c;
        do 
        {
            c = longText[i++];

        } while (c != ']');


        // check type 4
        for (var j = 0; j < longText.Length; j++)
        {
            c = longText[j];

            if (c == ']') continue; // skip

            // do something
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"pos = {pos}, i = {i}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be this way

```
do
{
    k++;
} while (!line[k].ToString().Contains('"' + "]" + '"'));
```